# Need help optimizing vacation planning Excel (sumproduct of 10000+ rows)

Tags: excel

In this picture you can see in column F to H what the raw data looks like and column A to D is what I need (but horizontal).

[image: table]

I transformed the data to show exact dates when employee is on vacation and not date ranges for example:

```
John    02.01.2018  03.01.2018  04.01.2018  05.01.2018  
John    07.01.2018  08.01.2018  09.01.2018  10.01.2018  
Tom     01.01.2018  02.01.2018  03.01.2018  04.01.2018  05.01.2018
Tom     07.01.2018  08.01.2018  09.01.2018      
Mark    04.01.2018  05.01.2018  06.01.2018      
Mark    08.01.2018  09.01.2018  10.01.2018
```

This way I can use sumproduct to fill my planning table and it works.I managed to do it for managers because the raw data is only 400 rows I use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(VMX!$G$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">""")-1;1)=Planner!$A3)*(INDIRECT("VMX!$O$2:$AS$"&COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">"""))=Planner!G$1)*(OFFSET(VMX!$M$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$M:$M;">""")-1;1)="X"))>0;"X";IF(SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(VMX!$G$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">""")-1;1)=Planner!$A3)*(INDIRECT("VMX!$O$2:$AS$"&COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">"""))=Planner!G$1)*(OFFSET(VMX!$M$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$M:$M;">""")-1;1)="Y"))>0;"Y";IF(SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(VMX!$G$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">""")-1;1)=Planner!$A3)*(INDIRECT("VMX!$O$2:$AS$"&COUNTIF(VMX!$G:$G;">"""))=Planner!G$1)*(OFFSET(VMX!$M$2;0;0;COUNTIF(VMX!$M:$M;">""")-1;1)="O"))>0;"O";"")))
```

I simplified this formula using name manager to this:

```
=IF(SPX>0;"X";IF(SPY>0;"Y";IF(SPO>0;"O";"")))
```

In sheet VMX is the data.

The data ranges should be dynamic because I used offset and indirect but when I try to use this for all employees which is 10k+ rows the excel just freezes.

Does anyone know more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your raw data to a table (tblVacDates). Then you can use a formula like this, using `COUNTIFS`.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(tblVacDates[Name];B$1,tblVacDates[Start];"<="&$A2;tblVacDates[End];">="&$A2)=0;"";"X")
```

Paste the formula to the other columns (don't drag). Then you can copy/drag down

[image]

Comment: >Paste the formula to the other columns (don't drag). The names could be 100+ also the names come from pivot table where each manager can choose his own employees.

Comment: @mandmi - So what's the problem? You don't have to paste them one at a time. Select cell B2. Copy. Select cells B3:B100. Paste. Select cell B2:B100. Drag down. Done. As an alternative you could use absolute columnnames. For example tblVacDates[[Name]:[Name]]. These you can also drag across columns.

Comment: Before you replied I used this: `=IF(COUNTIFS(RawData!$F$2:$F$34639;$A4;RawData!$K$2:$K$34639;"<="&EX$1;RawData!$L$2:$L$34639;">="&EX$1)=0;"";"X")` It works but it is even slower now. Does the table make it fast? Also I transposed it to horizontal.

Comment: Actually it is faster I think. With sumproduct Excel was unresponsive for 5 minutes. With this it také about 1 minute and it actually shows the calculatoon progress. Do you think it is possible to malé it even faster?

Comment: @mandmi - did you try converting the RawData to a table? It could be faster. I don't know for sure. That's all i have for now ;-)